# Implementing TFlers in my game

Tags: lua, resolution, love2d

i'm trying to design a game that was initially designed for 1680 x 1050.. however i implemented Tflers in my project and it not going that well.
First in my love.load i added:

```
function love.load()
TLfres.setScreen({w= 1680, h = 1200, full=true, vsync = false, aa=0}, 1, false, true)
end
```

Then in my love.draw():

```
function love.draw()
     TLfres.transform()
   love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(0,0,0) 
if GameState == "MainMenu" then
   love.graphics.draw(background,0,0)
   love.graphics.draw(picture, 200, 200)
   end
   if GameState == "PaintGame" then
   love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(20,191,243)
love.graphics.draw(easel, 640,360)
   love.graphics.draw(cursor, love.mouse.getX(), love.mouse.getY())
   end
TLfres.letterbox(16,9)
end
```

However i'm getting this error:

TLfres.lua.13: attempt to call field 'setMode' ( a nil value )

How to get rid of this error??
I realized that tlfres requires the old verison of love in order to work, however I want it on the newest version of love. how can I optimize it to work? Thanks!
Thanks guys!

Comment: The error is in the library, not the code you've shown us. This question can't be answered as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

As of [LÖVE 0.9.0](http://love2d.org/wiki/0.9.0), [love.graphics.setMode](http://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.setMode) was replaced with [love.window.setMode](http://love2d.org/wiki/love.window.setMode). Talk with the library creator about that.